# How can i add this sub query condition to existing query?

Tags: mysql

Excuse me for not being able to post the full query for some issues but in the query,If what i have is not sufficient please respond in the comments and i could refactor the full query. i have the last section looking like this :

```
path p1
 on as1.UpdateID = u_d1.UpdateID join
path p2 
on p2.UpdateID = u_d2.UpdateID  ;
```

I have another query like this

```
SELECT Count(People), UpdateID FROM path Group BY UpdateID;
```

I will like to add this query at the last section of the existing query. I tried something like this but the query is taking forever :

```
 path p1
 on p1.UpdateID = u_d1.UpdateID join
 path p2 
on as2.UpdateID = u_d2.UpdateID HAVING SUM(p2.People) = SUM(p1.People) ;
```

I first tried "`AND SUM(as2.People) = SUM(as1.People) ;`" But that is wrong i guess.

Is there anyway to do this ? Please if more information is required, ask before down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, dumb and straightforward, replacing "path" table with corresponding query

```
(SELECT Count(People) cnt, UpdateID FROM path Group BY UpdateID) as p1
 on as1.UpdateID = u_d1.UpdateID join
(SELECT Count(People) cnt, UpdateID FROM path Group BY UpdateID) as p2 
 on p2.UpdateID = u_d2.UpdateID and p1.cnt = p2.cnt ;
```

But, if it will work, it will be slow and inefficient - MySQL has poor performance on aggregate queries.
The better way would be to create "cache" table with pre-calculated sums and join that table instead.

Like

```
INSERT cache_table (UpdateId, cnt)
SELECT UpdateID, Count(People) cnt FROM path Group BY UpdateID
on duplicate key update cache_table.cnt = values(cnt)
```

then

```
cache_table as p1
 on as1.UpdateID = u_d1.UpdateID join
cache_table as p2 
 on p2.UpdateID = u_d2.UpdateID and p1.cnt = p2.cnt ;
```

And don't forget to update the cache_table regularly.

Comment: The second idea worked out pretty well